# Custom Notifications using bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap notifications to show informational messages to my end users. http://goodybag.github.io/bootstrap-notify/

And I have a `DIV` called

```
<div class="notifications bottom-right"></div>
```

In theory the library should be handling the JS I have made sure the library is loaded and it is but still no notification window is showing I don't know why I want this to happen on page load so user is told if has points pending.

How would I adapt the script tag to achieve that via `PHP`?.

```
<script>
    $('.bottom-right').notify({
        message: { text: 'Aw yeah, It works!' }
    }).show(); // for the ones that aren't closable and don't fade out   there is a .hide() function.
</script>
```

**Edit to show files in Header I have used wp enque obv**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fundrasing.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/wp-content/themes/gogreensoccer5/js/bootstrap-notify.js?ver=201202012'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='notifcations-css1-css'  href='http://fundrasing.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/wp-content/themes/gogreensoccer5/css/bootstrap-notify.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='notifcations-css2-css'  href='http://fundrasing.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/wp-content/themes/gogreensoccer5/css/styles/alert-blackgloss.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='notifcations-css3-css'  href='http://fundrasing.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/wp-content/themes/gogreensoccer5/css/styles/alert-bangtidy.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mwatz122/1k3s7m80/

Make sure you include all of the necessary libraries (both CSS and JS). In my JSFiddle example, I have included `bootstrap-notify.min.css`, `alert-bangtidy.min.css`, `alert-blackgloss.min.css`, and `bootstrap-notify.min.js` from a CDN.

If you want the notification to show when the page loads, you should include the JavaScript code within a `$(document).ready` block as shown.

```
<div class='notifications bottom-right'></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bottom-right').notify({
        message: {
            text: 'Aw yeah, It works!'
        }
    }).show();
});
```

**Edit:**

Your site is throwing an error when the page loads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).notify is not a function
```

This means the `bootstrap-notify.min.js` source file isn't detected. I would try referencing a CDN first, to make sure you can get it working. You should include `jQuery` and `Bootstrap` before the `bootstrap-notify.min.js` file in your header. You can use this as your CDN link `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js`.

Comment: @Mathew I have here but I cant seem to see the notificaiton work http://fundrasing.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/

Comment: You have both jQuery and Bootstrap included as well, right?

Comment: Yes U can see their there in my view source as should be i placed the div in wordpress footer in case that was issue but still no notification:-(

Comment: yeap but i do have  a background image on my site as you see wondering if it could be hiding it :-(

Comment: I copied and pasted exact what you posted in case was a typo issue

Comment: The .notifications class has a z-index of 9999, so unless you have something on your site with a higher value z-index then it should be visible.

Comment: Nope I def dont designed the css with that in mind kinda weird

Comment: I have added what i have in my header i have used wp enque for this purpose

Comment: Thanks Matheww how would i do this in php so that I can pass say a variable to the window ? Is their an easy way of doing that.

Comment: quite strange when i have the fulll js included why must the minified one also be included but good to no thanks can i just download this i hate relying on third party cds

Comment: You can download the file without referencing the CDN. I just thought trying to get the notifications working by referencing the CDN might narrow your search. Also you shouldn't NEED the minified version if you have the full version. Why do you need to pass a variable to the JS file?

Comment: I'm looking at your site now, you included the CDN as a stylesheet rather than a JavaScript file. Change this to a script: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js">

Comment: Another error here GET http://fundrasing.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/ajaxexample/js/notify.js?ver=4.3.1 404 (Not Found)

Comment: fixed that and still nothing god i love .net in comparing to php to debug